# How to create auto increment ID in mongoose (Node js) other than _id

Tags: node.js, mongoose

For Example on saving user userId value has to be something like U1001, on adding another record userId of that record has to be U1002

Answer (score 0):

Create a getNextSequence function that accepts a name of the sequence. The function uses the findAndModify() method to atomically increment the seq value and return this new value:

```
function getNextSequence(name) {
   var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
          {
            query: { _id: name },
            update: { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
            new: true
          }
   );

   return ret.seq;
}
```